# linux Remote GUI access from server

Tags: remote, gui

How can i get display of remote GUI ? I am using Ubuntu. What command lines should I use after ssh tunneling?
i tried

```
export DISPLAY=remote_host
```

and tried running a CUDA,Open CV related program and it replied

```
cannot connect to X server
```

Comment: Try adding `-X` to your ssh command.